# While Loop inside While Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with this code in that the second while loop only runs the first time through the code, and then also it makes it so that the $row['id'] does not get a value. Can you help me figure out where I went wrong with this?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM faq ORDER BY `order`");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sections ORDER BY `order`");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo  '<form action="../../includes/faqupdate.php" method="post" style="margin:40px;">';
  echo  '<input type="text" name="order" style="width:20px;text-align:center;" onclick="this.value=\'\';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?\'' . $row['order'] . '\':this.value;" value="' . $row['order'] . '">';
  echo  '<input type="text" name="heading" onclick="this.value=\'\';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?\'' . $row['heading'] . '\':this.value;" value="' . $row['heading'] . '">';
  echo  '<select name="section">';
  $section = $row['section'];
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
      $sectionname = $row['sectionname'];
      if ($sectionname == $section) {
        echo    '<option value="' . $sectionname . '" selected="selected">' . $sectionname . '</option>';
      } else {
            echo    '<option value="' . $sectionname . '">' . $sectionname . '</option>';
      }
  }
  echo      '</select>';
  echo      '<input type="text" name="id" style="width:20px;background-color:#CCC;text-align:center;" value="' . $row['id'] . '" readonly>';
  echo      '<textarea name="content" cols="98" rows="10">' . $row['content'] . '</textarea>';
  echo      '<input type="submit" name="submission" value="Update">';
  echo      '<input type="submit" name="submission" value="Delete">';
  echo  '</form>';
  }
```

Comment: use a different variable for $row in the inner loop.

Comment: that fixed the $row['id'] problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another issue I see with your code is that you will only be able fetch the result set of the query once. So instead get the values beforehand, and store them in a variable like so.

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sections ORDER BY `order`");
$sectionnames = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $sectionnames[] = $row['sectionname'];
}


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM faq ORDER BY `order`");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo  '<form action="../../includes/faqupdate.php" method="post" style="margin:40px;">';
  echo  '<input type="text" name="order" style="width:20px;text-align:center;" onclick="this.value=\'\';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?\'' . $row['order'] . '\':this.value;" value="' . $row['order'] . '">';
  echo  '<input type="text" name="heading" onclick="this.value=\'\';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?\'' . $row['heading'] . '\':this.value;" value="' . $row['heading'] . '">';
  echo  '<select name="section">';
  $section = $row['section'];
  foreach ($sectionnames as $sectionname) {
    if ($sectionname == $section) {
        echo    '<option value="' . $sectionname . '" selected="selected">' . $sectionname . '</option>';
    } else {
        echo    '<option value="' . $sectionname . '">' . $sectionname . '</option>';
    }
  }
  echo      '</select>';
  echo      '<input type="text" name="id" style="width:20px;background-color:#CCC;text-align:center;" value="' . $row['id'] . '" readonly>';
  echo      '<textarea name="content" cols="98" rows="10">' . $row['content'] . '</textarea>';
  echo      '<input type="submit" name="submission" value="Update">';
  echo      '<input type="submit" name="submission" value="Delete">';
  echo  '</form>';
  }
```

Comment: Can you help me with this question, it is using this same code just a little differently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376508/while-loop-only-works-on-first-run

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are redeclaring `$row`, try:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM faq ORDER BY `order`");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sections ORDER BY `order`");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo  '<form action="../../includes/faqupdate.php" method="post" style="margin:40px;">';
  echo  '<input type="text" name="order" style="width:20px;text-align:center;" onclick="this.value=\'\';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?\'' . $row['order'] . '\':this.value;" value="' . $row['order'] . '">';
  echo  '<input type="text" name="heading" onclick="this.value=\'\';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?\'' . $row['heading'] . '\':this.value;" value="' . $row['heading'] . '">';
  echo  '<select name="section">';
  $section = $row['section'];
  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
      $sectionname = $row2['sectionname'];
      if ($sectionname == $section) {
        echo    '<option value="' . $sectionname . '" selected="selected">' . $sectionname . '</option>';
      } else {
            echo    '<option value="' . $sectionname . '">' . $sectionname . '</option>';
      }
  }
  echo      '</select>';
  echo      '<input type="text" name="id" style="width:20px;background-color:#CCC;text-align:center;" value="' . $row['id'] . '" readonly>';
  echo      '<textarea name="content" cols="98" rows="10">' . $row['content'] . '</textarea>';
  echo      '<input type="submit" name="submission" value="Update">';
  echo      '<input type="submit" name="submission" value="Delete">';
  echo  '</form>';
  }
```

Comment: that only fixes my second problem

Comment: the option tag only shows up on the first instance of the while loop

Answer (score 2):

Rename your `$row` in your second while condition for `$row2`