# While Loop Only Works On First Run

Tags: php, mysql

The foreach prints out each of the headers, and I get all the accordions, but everything but the first accordion are empty. What am I missing?

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sections ORDER BY `order`");
    $sectionnames = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $sectionnames[] = $row['sectionname'];
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM faq ORDER BY `order`");

    foreach ($sectionnames as $sectionname) {
            echo '<h3 id="sectionname">' . $sectionname . '</h3>';
            echo '<div id="accordion">';
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                if ($sectionname == $row['section']) {
                    echo '<h3>' . $row['heading'] . '</h3>';
                    echo '<div>' . $row['content'] . '</div>';
                } 
           }
           echo '</div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your schema I can't be sure, but it looks like faq is related to section by sectionname. If that's true, something like this:

```
foreach ($sectionnames as $sectionname) {
        echo '<h3 id="sectionname">' . $sectionname . '</h3>';
        echo '<div id="accordion">';
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM faq where section = '$sectionname' ORDER BY `order`");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {   
           echo '<h3>' . $row['heading'] . '</h3>';
           echo '<div>' . $row['content'] . '</div>';    
       }
       echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div id="accordion">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

This will effectively consume every row from your query result and put it inside the first accordion.

For every other `$sectionname`, your `$result` will already have been exhausted and will therefore generate empty `accordion`s, since you do not realize any new queries.

Comment: so what do I need to do to fix it

Comment: This is normal behaviour. You're fetching data row by row from the resource. Once it's finished, resource pointer is at the end. That's why you have to reset it. What you can do instead is create an empty array before your while and inside of it do $data[] = $row. Your $data var will now contain all the results that you can reuse.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add this code right before the while loop

```
mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
```

Comment: That may work, but it's doing so by useless repeat scan over the result set as Arthur noted. You should let SQL do the work. Take a look at my answer for how to improve it more in that direction.